# valueChanged method is not invoked when only the selected column is changed

Tags: java, swing

Right now I have a JTable with a ListSelectionModel and an attached ListSelectionListener:

```
ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = tblCalendar.getSelectionModel();
    listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new SharedListSelectionHandler());

static class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {

            //etc.
        }
    }
```

The valueChanged method is not being invoked when my selection changes in the same row. How can I invoke the valueChanged method when the selected cell is only changing in the row?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I invoke the valueChanged method when the selected cell is only changing in the row?

You get the `ListSelectionModel` from the `TableColumnModel` of the `JTable`:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
ListSelectionModel lsm = tcm.getSelectionModel();
lsm.addListSelectionListener(...);
```

Comment: Now I have the same issue, except with columns. When I change my selection within the column, the valueChanged method is not invoked. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: *Am I missing something obvious?* - You need to use both listeners, one for the row and one for the column.